# Mices and rats: differences between shǔ, lǎo shǔ, Xiǎo lǎo shǔ, etc

Tags: translation

What is the difference between all the different available kinds of rat and mices, like shǔ, lǎo shǔ, Xiǎo lǎo shǔ?

Can 鼠 be used alone?

Is 小家鼠 the proper word to mean a nice little mouse in a colloquial sentence (e.g. not in a scientific essay)?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/how-to-distinguish-between-rat-and-mouse-in-chinese

Answer (score 1):

In most conditions, Chinese Mandarin doesn't divide "rat" and "mouse", but 鼠 and 老鼠 can mean different creatures. 鼠 means various of mouse-like creatures, like voles, hamsters, guinea pigs and so on, while 老鼠 only means rat, that grey little creature.

Hope it helps, I learned these from an online lesson I was taking, it's the ECL(eChineseLearning), they have got a free trial, and basically that's why I enroll their classes. Just for your consideration if you want to learn Chinese systematically, visit at http://www.echineselearning.com/free-trial/ for a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the related question indicated by Krazer ([How to distinguish between rat and mouse in Chinese?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1317/11269)) are quite explicative:

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1331/11269

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1330/11269

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1516/11269

So, summing up: in common language, do not make distinction among "rat" and "mouse"; use 老鼠 for both. 鼠 indicates an animal with a little head and long tail; it should not be used alone, but together with other morphemes to form words.

Thanks!